# Javax validation not giving error messages

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm using javax validation. I have this xml:

```
<context:annotation-config/> 
    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "index" view -->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="front"/>
    ....
 <context:component-scan base-package="fi.utu.tuha.controller" />'
```

And controller:

```
public String ready(@ModelAttribute("netdriveOrder")@Valid NetdriveOrder netdriveOrder,
             Model model, BindingResult result) {
       if (result.hasErrors()) {
           return "order";
       } else {
           return "order_confirmed";
   }
```

I don't see a fault, but I get this:

Exception

```
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException:
Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String
fi.utu.tuha.controller.NetDriveOrderFormController.ready(fi.utu.tuha.domain.NetdriveOrder,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)];
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model
attribute. Check your handler method signature!
```

Stack Trace

```
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:181)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
com.nixu.security.sso.web.HeaderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(HeaderAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 2):

`BindingResult` should be declared next to the corresponding model attribute:

```
public String ready(
    @ModelAttribute("netdriveOrder") @Valid NetdriveOrder netdriveOrder,
    BindingResult result,
    Model model) { ... }
```